# C#: How to make window go really fullscreen

Tags: c#, window, fullscreen

Hello I would like to ask how to make window in C# application truly go fullscren and whether it is even possible ? I don't also mean the set maximized and undecorated approach but rather true fullscreen like in java by setting window to fullscreen( I mean so that I can switch resolution of screen in app and if I alt-tab out of the app it switches back to normal resolution[There should be winapi  way of doing it at least since it is possible in java])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, in Windows forms you need to play with FormBorderStyle and WindowState
 here is an example:

```
    private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == 'F')
        {
            if (FormBorderStyle == FormBorderStyle.None)
            {
                FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
                WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            }
            else
            {
                FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            }
        }
    }
```

That will alternate you from FullScreen and normal mode.

And if you want to go back to normal mode when user alt-tab out of the app add code to the deactivate event of the form:

```
    private void Form1_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FormBorderStyle == FormBorderStyle.None)
        {
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Okay. So there is no  `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().setFullScreenWindow(this);`
equivalent ? Please note it actually changes the display itself if I decide to switch resolution after that call. Plus it has a very good taskbar and window switching behaviour I found hard to reproduce by just maximizing a window in java.

Sorry if that seems to be a bit of basic question and I will use your advice if there is no alternative, I just had a bit of bad experience using this approach in java so I am trying  to avoid it.

Comment: Here is a sample project using my approach: https://github.com/heldersepu/csharp-proj/tree/master/FullScreen